# Error while save as template SharePoint 2010

Tags: template

When I try to save a site as a template I'm getting an error.

Can anyone help me?

Following lines from ULS log:

```
SPSolutionExporter: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).    
 at System.Guid..ctor(String g)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart.get_ItemContext()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart.get_ShowToolbarWithRibbon()    
 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterListFormWebPart.Write15_ListFormWebPart(String n, String ns, ListFormWebPart o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)    
 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterListFormWebPart.Write16_WebPart(Object o)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)    
 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.SerializeWebPartXml(Boolean shouldExcludeSpecialProperties, TextWriter writer)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.WriteXmlAsUtf8(Boolean shouldExcludeSpecialProperties)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.GetWebPartXml(WebPart webPart, Boolean shouldUTF8Encode, Boolean shouldExcludeSpecialProperties, Boolean export)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.ExportWebPart(WebPart webPart, XmlWriter writer)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInWeb(String workflowTemplateName)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GenerateSolutionFiles()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebAsSolution()
```